# Integrating a curve within boundaries

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to integrate a curve within certain boundaries. I have two arrays corresponding to the y and x values. I'm using `np.trapz()` but I only want to integrate up to a certain x value and not over the entire curve. The arrays are quite large with thousands of elements. So, for instance, I want to find the area under the curve `y(x)` but only from `x=0` to `x=500` using `np.trapz()` or some other method if there is a better way.

Comment: what stops you from removing all (x,y) pairs for which x >= x_max from your arrays?

Comment: (note that this approximation will only work if the x are sufficiently dense. If that's not the case, interpolating the y value at x_max and adding(x_max, y_interpolated) should yield better results.

Comment: Okay. How do I remove the x>=x_max?